# Install W11 Home without an Internet connection

Tags: windows-11

How can you Install W11 Home without an Internet connection, I have tried but it insist's on an internet connection and a Microsoft account.

Any way to set up a regular user account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reach the “Let’s Connect You To A Network” page, hit “Shift” and “F10” on the keyboard at the same time.

This will bring up the Command Prompt

In the cmd window, type in “taskmgr.exe” and press “Enter” on the keyboard. This will bring up the Task Manager window so you can see all running processes.
Expand the Task Manager by clicking the “More Details” button, and then find the process:

“Network Connection Flow.”

Select this process and then hit the “End Task” button.

Now you can close these newly opened windows and return to the Windows 11 setup, where you can enter a name for a local account.

Answer (score 1):

Some additions to the answer by @Moab:

At the "Let’s connect you to a network" screen, press the
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
keys together, to launch the Command Prompt window on the top of
setup wizard window.

Now type in the Command Prompt window any one of the following two
commands and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
ipconfig /release
```

Or :

```
taskkill /F /IM oobenetworkconnectionflow.exe
```

Windows 11 setup will now skip the Internet connection step and you’ll
see the next step to create and setup a local user account to complete
the installation process.

These commands work at the moment, but there is no guarantee that Microsoft
will not block them in the future.